# Type 'FormGroup<any> | null' is not assignable to type 'AbstractControlLike' with Angular material stepControl

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-forms

```
 <mat-step [editable]="true" [stepControl]="productDetailsFormGroup$ | async">
            <ng-template matStepLabel>Product details</ng-template>
            <ng-template matStepContent>
              <fetebird-ui-product-details></fetebird-ui-product-details>
            </ng-template>
  </mat-step>
```

In the component

```
readonly productDetailsFormGroup$: Observable<FormGroup>;

constructor(private productStore: ProductStore) {
    this.productDetailsFormGroup$ = this.productStore.selectProductDetailsForm$;
  }
```

**Error**

```
error TS2322: Type 'FormGroup<any> | null' is not assignable to type 'AbstractControlLike'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'AbstractControlLike'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `async` pipe is always [T | null](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/14.2.3/packages/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.ts#L110) or `null`, and the `stepControl` doesn't accept `null`.

You can add `*ngIf` to make sure it's not `null` before using it, like the following:

```html
<mat-step
  *ngIf="productDetailsFormGroup$ | async as stepControl"
  [editable]="true"
  [stepControl]="stepControl"
>
  <ng-template matStepLabel>Product details</ng-template>
  <ng-template matStepContent>
    <fetebird-ui-product-details></fetebird-ui-product-details>
  </ng-template>
</mat-step>
```